# My App is not asking for POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission

Tags: android, permissions

My app wants to send notifications but the new permission added in android default 33 is denied and somehow android doesn't automatically prompt the user when trying to create a notification channel. Is there something I'm missing? If not, how (and when) do I apply for Permission?

This is my SplashScreenActivity, I already have a function that requests location access, I would like to know how to request POST_NOTIFICATIONS

```
package com.alidelivery.entrega.ui.Activity;

import static com.alidelivery.entrega.util.Constant.GPS_PROVIDED;
import static com.alidelivery.entrega.util.Constant.INTENT_DOMAINS;
import static com.alidelivery.entrega.util.Constant.REQUEST_ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION;
import static com.alidelivery.entrega.util.Constant.REQUEST_FINE_BACKGROUND_LOCATION;
import static com.alidelivery.entrega.util.Constant.REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION;
import static com.alidelivery.entrega.util.Constant.STORE_COLOR;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

import com.alidelivery.entrega.R;
import com.alidelivery.entrega.api.Api;
import com.alidelivery.entrega.network.RetrofitInstance;
import com.alidelivery.entrega.util.CallbackWithRetry;
import com.alidelivery.entrega.util.Constant;
import com.alidelivery.entrega.util.Funtionality;
import com.alidelivery.entrega.util.LocationHandler;
import com.alidelivery.entrega.util.PackageVerificationListener;
import com.alidelivery.entrega.util.SharePref;
import com.google.android.material.dialog.MaterialAlertDialogBuilder;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.Arrays;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;

public class SplashScreenActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private static final String TAG = SplashScreenActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    static int multiplePermissionCount = 0;
    long timestart;
    private ImageView screen_iv;
    private LocationHandler permissionHandler;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private AlertDialog materialAlertDialogBuilder;
    private AlertDialog _termsAndConditionDialog;


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);
        SharePref sharePref = new SharePref(this);
        permissionHandler = new LocationHandler(this);


        screen_iv = findViewById(R.id.screen_iv);
        Animation fade_in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fade_in);
        screen_iv.startAnimation(fade_in);
        ShowTermsAndConditionsDialog();




        //firstverify
        if (!SharePref.getBooleanFromPref(Constant.ANLIVER_CHECKED)) {
            //if anliverChecked false then
            if (!SharePref.getBooleanFromPref(Constant.ANLIVER)) {
                // if anliver false then call for api to check ANLIVER
                Funtionality.checkAndroidPackage(this, new PackageVerificationListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        getSettings();
                        _termsAndConditionDialog.show();
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(String message) {
                        Toast.makeText(SplashScreenActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            //if ANLIVER(First time) checking is true then check for ANLIVER
            if (SharePref.getBooleanFromPref(Constant.ANLIVER)) {
                // if this is true then start app
                getSettings();
                if(SharePref.getBooleanFromPref(Constant.TERMS_AND_CONDITION_AGREED)){
                    HandlePermission();
                    if (permissionHandler.getPermissionGranted())
                        StartApp();
                }else{
                    _termsAndConditionDialog.show();
                }

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please try to install Licensed App", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }

    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void ShowTermsAndConditionsDialog() {

        AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SplashScreenActivity.this)
                .setTitle(R.string.tnc_title)
                .setMessage(Funtionality.getAppNameFromPkgName(this).concat(getResources().getString(R.string.tnc_message)))
                .setPositiveButton(R.string.tnc_positiveButton, (dialog, which) -> {
                    SharePref.setBooleanPref(Constant.TERMS_AND_CONDITION_AGREED,true);
                    HandlePermission();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.tnc_negativeButton, (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss());

        alertBuilder.setOnDismissListener(dialog -> {
            if(!SharePref.getBooleanFromPref(Constant.TERMS_AND_CONDITION_AGREED)){
                _termsAndConditionDialog.show();
            }
        });

        _termsAndConditionDialog = alertBuilder.create();
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private void HandlePermission() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            permissionHandler.takePermission();
        } else {
            permissionHandler.locationEnabled();
        }
    }

    private void getSettings() {
        if (!SharePref.getDataFromPref(Constant.ANLIVER_BASE_URL).equals(""))
            Constant.BASE_URL = SharePref.getDataFromPref(Constant.ANLIVER_BASE_URL);

        Api apiService = RetrofitInstance.getRetrofitIntance().create(Api.class);

        apiService.getSetting(STORE_COLOR).enqueue(new CallbackWithRetry<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response) {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    try {
                        throw new Exception("Server error");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        super.onFailure(call, e);
                    }
                } else {
                    String json = new Gson().toJson(response.body());
                    try {
                        JSONObject object = new JSONObject(json.trim());
                        SharePref.setDataPref(STORE_COLOR, object.getString("value"));
                        Log.d(TAG, "Preference: " + SharePref.getDataFromPref(STORE_COLOR));
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        apiService.getSetting(INTENT_DOMAINS).enqueue(new Callback<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Object> call, Response<Object> response) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: Code: " + response.code() + " Successful :" + response.isSuccessful() + "Body :" + response.body());
                if (response.code() == 200) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                        String intentDomains;
                        if (!response.body().toString().equals("")) {
                            intentDomains = response.body().toString();
                            SharePref.setDataPref(INTENT_DOMAINS, intentDomains);
                        } else
                            SharePref.setDataPref(INTENT_DOMAINS, "[]");

                    } else {
                        SharePref.setDataPref(INTENT_DOMAINS, "[]");
                    }
                } else {
                    SharePref.setDataPref(INTENT_DOMAINS, "[]");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Object> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: " + t.getMessage());
                SharePref.setDataPref(INTENT_DOMAINS, "[]");
            }
        });

    }

    public void StartApp() {
        long stopTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long total = stopTime - timestart;
        Log.d(TAG, "Timer: " + total);
//        Toast.makeText(this,String.valueOf(total),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashScreenActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        Log.d(TAG, "REQUEST CODE: " + requestCode + " permission :" + Arrays.toString(permissions));
        //for sdkbelow 29
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION) {
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                        showDialog();
                    } else {
                        StartApp();
                    }
                } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    permissionHandler.takePermission();
                }
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: PERMISSION Background");
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
                        materialAlertDialogBuilder.dismiss();
                    }
                    StartApp();
                } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    permissionHandler.takePermission();
                }
            }
        }

        if (requestCode == REQUEST_FINE_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: LENGTH " + grantResults.length + "  " + Arrays.toString(grantResults));
            if (grantResults.length > 0) {
                if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION}, REQUEST_ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);
                    }
                } else if (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: PERMISSION DENIED");
                    if (permissions.length == 2) {
                        multiplePermissionCount++;
                        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: PERMISSION DENIED" + multiplePermissionCount);
                        if (multiplePermissionCount == 2) {
                            Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.splash_screen), "Você deve ir em Configurações e conceder a permissão do Local, permitir o tempo todo, \n \npara usar este aplicativo.", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            permissionHandler.takePermission();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        materialAlertDialogBuilder = new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(this)
                .setTitle("Usar localização em segundo plano?")
                .setMessage("Permita o acesso à localização em segundo plano para manter seu rastreamento de localização por seu cliente")
                .setNegativeButton("Cancelar", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                    dialogInterface.dismiss();
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Permitir", (dialogInterface, i) -> {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION}, REQUEST_ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION);
                }).show();
    }

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == Constant.REQUEST_FOR_GPS) {
            switch (resultCode) {
                case RESULT_OK:
                    GPS_PROVIDED = true;
                    permissionHandler.takePermission();
                    if (permissionHandler.getPermissionGranted())
                        StartApp();
                    break;
                case RESULT_CANCELED:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "O GPS não está ativado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    finish();
                    break;
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
void requestPermission() {
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String [](Manifest.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS), 0 );
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String [](Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION), 1 );
}
```

You can pass an array of permissions as the second parameter of `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` if you request for multiple permission or ask one by one like the above example.

The override method `onRequestPermissionsResult()` is invoked when permission is granted.

Note: If the permission request is declined by the user you can use the `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` method to request permission once again. If it is again declined, `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions()` will not work any more, either you have to navigate to the Settings page and grand the permission or reinstall the app.

Comment: @PeterSmith I used the code you posted here, but when I put it in my app it can only ask for location or notification permission, my app needs both location and notification permissions. Is there a way to ask for both permissions at once?